# Detecting access point tree on POX Spanning Tree

Tags: sdn, openflow, mininet

I have created a topology at Mininet-Wifi with 4 access point and 2 station.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller,OVSKernelSwitch, RemoteController
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mn_wifi.cli import CLI_wifi
from mn_wifi.net import Mininet_wifi

def topology():

net = Mininet_wifi( controller=RemoteController, link=TCLink, switch=OVSKernelSwitch )

print "*** Creating nodes"
ap1 = net.addAccessPoint( 'ap1', ssid= 'ssid-ap1', mode= 'g', channel= '1', position='30,70,0', range='20' )
ap2 = net.addAccessPoint( 'ap2', ssid= 'ssid-ap2', mode= 'g', channel= '1', position='70,110,0', range='20' )
ap3 = net.addAccessPoint( 'ap3', ssid= 'ssid-ap3', mode= 'g', channel= '1', position='110,70,0', range='20' )
ap4 = net.addAccessPoint( 'ap4', ssid= 'ssid-ap4', mode= 'g', channel= '1', position='70,30,0', range='20' )
sta1 = net.addStation( 'sta1', mac='00:00:00:00:00:01', ip='10.0.0.1/8', position='28,68,0', range='10' )
sta2 = net.addStation( 'sta2', mac='00:00:00:00:00:02', ip='10.0.0.2/8', position='108,68,0', range='10' )
c1 = net.addController( 'c1', controller=RemoteController, ip="127.0.0.1" )

"""plot graph"""
net.plotGraph(max_x=220, max_y=150)

# Comment out the following two lines to disable AP
print "*** Enabling association control (AP)"
net.configureWifiNodes()

print "*** Creating links and associations"
net.addLink( ap1, ap2 )
net.addLink( ap2, ap3 )
net.addLink( ap4, ap3 )
net.addLink( ap1, ap4 )

net.addLink( ap1, sta1 )
net.addLink( ap3, sta2 )

print "*** Starting network"
net.build()
c1.start()
ap1.start( [c1] )
ap2.start( [c1] )
ap3.start( [c1] )
ap4.start( [c1] )

print "*** Running CLI"
CLI_wifi( net )

print "*** Stopping network"
net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel( 'info' )
    topology()
```

and then when running this code the topology like that

[image: Mininet-wifi topology]

I run POX controller with that features like below

```
sudo ~/pox/pox.py forwarding.l2_learning openflow.spanning_tree --no-flood --hold-down log.level --DEBUG samples.pretty_log --DEBUG openflow.discovery host_tracker --DEBUG info.packet_dump
```

After all that I pinged sta1 to sta2 and ping was succesful but I wanna learn ping is going on which way?

ap1->ap2->ap3 or ap1->ap4->ap3

How can i check the way? And also I wanna add a question to that question. When I was checking openflow.discovery messages, I encountered that message

```
[openflow.discovery     ] link detected: 00-00-00-00-00-04|4096.2 -> 00-00-00-00-00-03|4096.3
```

What this message mean? What is 4096.2? and 4096.3? I am really struggled with understanding that subject. Please help. I also wanna add mininet-wifi and pox tags but not have enough reputation.

Comment: Oh no. No one knows that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. After all that I pinged sta1 to sta2 and ping was succesful but I wanna learn ping is going on which way

A. You can use ovs-ofctl and check flows table out.

Q2. And also I wanna add a question to that question. When I was checking openflow.discovery messages, I encountered that message

A. 00-00-00-00-00-04|4096 is the dpid whereas 2 the interface number. Take a look at [this code](https://github.com/noxrepo/pox/blob/412a6adb38cb646748c8cfb657549787ab6d2e88/pox/openflow/discovery.py#L243).

Comment: Why 4096 is there? Do that have special meaning?

Comment: Not sure why 4096, but I've figured out the reason. According your code the default dpid for ap1 is: `10000000000000001`. However, if the dpid is `0000000000000001`, 4096 disappears. That said, you can try `ap1 = net.addAccessPoint( 'ap1', ssid= 'ssid-ap1', mode= 'g', channel= '1', position='30,70,0', range='20', dpid='1' )` and you won't see 4096 anymore. Ps. A new `git pull` and `sudo make install` of the mn-wifi source code is needed.